# Perfect Continuous

Tags: tenses, past-tense, perfect-aspect, continuous-aspect

I know we use Past Perfect Continuous when an event in the past continue up until another event in the past:

> I had been talking with her for over an hour before Tony arrived.

1. Can we use it when an event in the past continue up until a specific time in the past?

> I had been talking with her until 8 o'clock.

I have the same question here with the Future Perfect Continuous:

2. Can we use it if the event continues up until a specific time?

> By 8 o'clock Tomorrow, I will have been jogging for 10 hours.
> I will have been jogging for 10 hours until 8 o'clock Tomorrow.

Do we use the perfect continuous forms when an event continues up until an another event or time and even further in the past or the future?

> I will have been jogging for 10 hours until 8 o'clock Tomorrow.

3. That can mean I'll stop the jogging at 8 o'clock and it can mean I will continue my jogging after 8 o'clock. Is this right?

Thank you for the answer in advance!

Comment: Hi @makaveli123, Welcome to EL&U, I am sorry but your question sounds too basic for this community. Why not try our sister community ell.stackexchange.com ? They're a more suitable site for beginners.

Comment: This is actually, to my mind, a difficult question.

Comment: I find it an intriguing question.  There's a difference I don't grasp between "before X" and "until X".  I could say "had been talking before X" but never "had been talking until X"

Answer (score 1):

I think this is one of those times where people respond differently to the aspectual elements of the verb in conjunction with other time markers. I will tell you what my own ear hears.

There is a very big difference between "By 10AM tomorrow" and "Until 10AM tomorrow", so I won't address your future question, only the Past Perfect Continuous.

> <sup>OK</sup> I will be sitting in this chair until 10AM.
>
> <sup>OK</sup> I was sitting in the chair until 10AM.
>
> <sup>marginal, to my ear</sup> I had been sitting in the chair *until*
>   10AM.

I feel a little discord between the prospective sense of **until** and the retrospective aspect of the past perfect.

One way to make it sound better to me is to make it habitual, rather than incidental:

**I had been {sitting in the chair until 10AM} *all semester*.**

Another way is to move the temporal phrase to the front, a difference that may be a specious difference. I'm just reporting what my "ear" hears.

**Until 10AM, I had been sitting in the chair.**

It's as if at the head of the statement, "Until 10AM" gets more easily translated to "*Before* 10AM" than it does when it's at the tail.

Another way is to add some additional time elements:

**I had been sitting in the chair until 10AM, *when there came a knock at the door*.**